# How to get DateOfBirth using age in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calc

I have user age, month and day something like 18 year 2 month and 5 days. I need to return user `DateOfBirth` using these params. How can I find user `DateOfBirth` from year, month and day?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: If someone is born on 29th Feb 2004, how old do they believe they are on 28th Feb 2005 (since it will impact the answer)?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a mathematics question? Think carefully if this is about how to mathematically solve this problem and that after you know that you can easily implement it in code.

Comment: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(1990, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0);` Where last three zeroes is time. Above will give `12/1/1990 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: @Flater, I working on Hospital Bill Management Solution where operator  like to insert age in year. month and day rather than dateofbirth.

Comment: @FaishalAhammad I have added an answer, try it out

Comment: If you ask me how old I am in years, months and days, I have to *stop and work that out from my DOB*. If the operators are asking for this information only for your system to then have to *undo* this (potentially fragile and incorrect calculation), do you not see that you have a *strong* argument for suggesting that an operational change would improve this for all concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution and it's works for me.

```
 public static DateTime GetDateOfBirth(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        int currentYear = today.Year;
        int currentDay = today.Day;
        int currentMonth = today.Month;

        if (day >= currentDay)
        {
            currentMonth--;
            currentDay += DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);
        }

        if (month >= currentMonth)
        {
            currentMonth += 12;
            currentYear--;
        }

        return new DateTime(currentYear - year, currentMonth - month, currentDay - day);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use AddDays/Months/Years with negative number to actually subtract Days/Months/Years from date.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine("Today's Date:" + now.ToString());

int years = 18;
int months = 2;
int days = 5;
now = now.AddYears((-1) * years);
now = now.AddMonths((-1) * months);
now = now.AddDays((-1) * days);

Console.WriteLine("Date Of Birth:" + now.ToString());

return now;
```

[image]